# What's the fourier transformation in spherical coordinates?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

Suppose a function in spherical coordinates $f(r,\phi,\theta)$. Ask for the Fourier transformation of such function.

Suppose that the function $f$ was symmetric with respect $\phi,\theta$, i.e. $f(r,\phi,\theta)=f(\theta)$.
Then what's the spherical coordinates Fourier transformation for such function?

Because, the usual definition $$\int_{0}^\infty f(r,\phi,\theta) r^2dr \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^\pi d\theta   e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}}$$ didn't seem to quite apply. Since $\vec{x}=(r,\phi,\theta)$ and $\vec{p}=(p_r,p_\phi,p_\theta)$, the latter doesn't even seemed to be properly defined. Even if one treat it as a one dimensional cases, will the coefficient be $1/\sqrt{2\pi}^3$ or just $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$?

How to do the fourier transformation in spherical coordinates?

Comment: There seems to be a typo? If $f$ is symmetric with respect to $\phi$, $\theta$, then it's $f(r)$, not $f(\theta)$.

Comment: The invariant measure of the sphere $S^2$ induces a pushforward distribution on $\mathbb R^3$ supported in $S^2$. The Fourier transform of this distribution is given by Bessel harmonics, so i guess its possible to express the Fourier transform in $\mathbb R^3$ as a combination of those Bessels functions and spherical harmonics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics